# Database schema is not in sync for a nullable column

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mariadb

Just found out `doctrine:schema:validate` fires an error:

> [ERROR] The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.

So I tried to `doctrine:schema:update --force --complete --dump-sql` which was successful:

> The following SQL statements will be executed:
>
> ```
>  ALTER TABLE user CHANGE last_login `last_login` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;
> ```
>
> Updating database schema...
>
> ```
>  1 query was executed
> ```
>
> [OK] Database schema updated successfully!

But if I run `doctrine:schema:validate` again it throws the same error regarding schema not in sync.

I have checked Database table field definition and it looks good:

```
`last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL
```

And this is how a column is defined:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $last_login;
```

I have found this: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/2825

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of `doctrine/dbal` do you use?

Comment: doctrine.dbal.server_version: '5.7'

Comment: No, I mean the version of the installed package (i.e. what is shown when running `composer show`).

Answer (score 1):

In your `config.yml` or `doctrine.yaml` (dependending on the Symfony's version), set proper server version of your database server. E.g.:

```
doctrine:
    # …
    dbal:
        # …
        server_version: mariadb-10.2.15
```

Note the `mariadb` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Doctrine has problems determining the correct MySQL API version when trying to derive the server version from a MariaDB installation.

It may help to define a MySQL version number in your configuration. It did for me in several projects, e.g. when using MariaDB on Debian Stretch.

```
# app/config/config.yml

doctrine:
    # …
    dbal:
        # …
        server_version: 5.7
```

This will have the effect that Doctrine skips the auto-detection of the MySQL version and uses a recent API.

Comment: it is defined though: `doctrine.dbal.server_version: '5.7'`

Comment: Could you try setting it to `5.6` (clear cache afterwards)?

Comment: Sorry, no as I have migrated to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I changed the DATABASE_URL in my .env.local and it worked.
Before (did not work)

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/db?serverVersion=10.4.12
```

After (worked finally)

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/db?serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.12
```